# Json loads fails on mqtt message

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing, decoding

I'm trying to parse the messages sent on an MQTT topic as JSONs, but when i try to call **json.loads()** on the decoded string, the code goes into exception:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 153 (char 152)
```

The code is the following:

```
    def on_message_mqtt(self, client, userdata, message):
        m_decode = message.payload.decode('utf-8')
        logger.info(m_decode)
        m_in = json.loads(m_decode)
        logger.info(m_in)
```

While the payload of the messages has the following format:

```
{"Timestamp":"2021-05-24-13:27:13.450","AI":[1204,7,0,4,18,2,1176,802,11,0,381,2496,0,0,810,1282],"DI":[false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]}
```

I tried to put the text into a string and **loads()** is able to parse it, so I bet that the problem is on the initial string decoding.

Here you can see a print of the decoded string, and then the error on the call to json.loads():

```
2021-05-24 16:31:47 - INFO - {"Timestamp":"2021-05-24-14:31:44.790","AI":[912,9,0,2,16,2,886,605,11,0,321,1924,1,963,620,9],"DI":[false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]}
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "router.py", line 136, in run
    self.mqtt.loop_forever()
  File "/opt/control/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1779, in loop_forever
    rc = self.loop(timeout, max_packets)
  File "/opt/control/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1181, in loop
    rc = self.loop_read(max_packets)
  File "/opt/control/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1572, in loop_read
    rc = self._packet_read()
  File "/opt/control/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2310, in _packet_read
    rc = self._packet_handle()
  File "/opt/control/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2940, in _packet_handle
    return self._handle_pubrel()
  File "/opt/control/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3246, in _handle_pubrel
    self._handle_on_message(message)
  File "/opt/control/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3444, in _handle_on_message
    self.on_message(self, self._userdata, message)
  File "router.py", line 87, in on_message_mqtt
    logger.info(json.loads(m_decode), exc_info=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 151 (char 150)
```

Comment: Can you see if there's a null byte at the end of your string?

Comment: the problem was indeed cause by a NUL char at the end of the byte.... :D

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the error, character 152 is the square bracket closing the arroy of the value for the key of "DI" `]` which would imply incorrect parsing using the `payload.decode` function

Can you check if this works

```
  def on_message_mqtt(self, client, userdata, message):
        m_in =  json.loads(message.decode("utf-8"))
        logger.info(m_in)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the MQTT message cannot be decoded directly, you have decode the payload instead.

I found out that the message had a NUL character at the end that was causing the unexpected behaviour.